# Obtaining all values of particular key as an array from an array of hashmaps in a compact and(or) quick way

Tags: arrays, loops, perl, hashmap, list-comprehension

I have a perl hashmap of the sort

```
my %data= (
    'John' => {
        'company' => 'xxx',
        'address' => 'San Francisco',
        'contact' => ['phone1', 'phone2']
    },
    'Alice' => {
        'company' => 'yyy',
        'address' => 'Boston',
        'contact' => ['phone3', 'phone4']
    },
);
```

Is there a way I can fetch all company names into a variable as an array without looping through the hashmap?
i.e, `('xxx', 'yyy')`

I have tried the following which does work but would like a more compact solution similar to list comprehension in python as mentioned below.

```
@companies = ();
for my $person_data (values %data)
{
    push(@companies, $person_data{'company'});
}
```

In python, I could achieve this using list comprehension as following:
`companies = [person_data['company'] for person_data in data.values()]`

Comment: What have you tried, and where di you get stuck? Also, note that you data structure does not look like Perl hash, but rather like a JSON string, which makes your question a bit unclear.

Comment: I'm saying the Perl hash is being loaded from a JSON of the sort I have mentioned above.
Obviously I have tried looping through the hash and pushing the company names into an array. But I need to know if there is a more cleaner, faster way to do it.
For ex: an array can be converted to hash with a simple `%hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array;`
In python, even though I still loop through the hash/dictionary, I can write the code in a single line as following `companies = [value['company'] for value in data.values()]`. It'll suffice if I can do the same in Perl as well.

Comment: Please show next time a valid Perl hash instead of json. It is clear what you want to do, but a Perl hash saves time for the people who want to answer the question. See an example in my question. You can also get it from your code using `Data::Dumper` module. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl equivalent of Python list comprehension is [`map`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), so you can use something like `@companies = map { $_->{company} } values %name_to_contact;`.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw( say );

my %name_to_contact = (
    'John' => {
        'company' => 'xxx',
        'address' => 'San Francisco',
        'contact' => ['phone1', 'phone2']
    },
    'Alice' => {
        'company' => 'yyy',
        'address' => 'Boston',
        'contact' => ['phone3', 'phone4']
    },
);

my @companies = map { $_->{company} } values %name_to_contact;

say "@companies";
# Prints:
# xxx yyy
```

Here, I used a valid Perl hash, the equivalent of the json you showed. I used single quotes as appropriate, which is in places where variable interpolation is not required.
`values %name_to_contact` : returns the unordered list of values of the input hash, that is, the list of anonymous hashes.
`map { $_->{company} } values %name_to_contact` : takes the list of values of the input hash, and for each element (an anonymous hash) assigns it to `$_`. `$_->{company}` is the value of `company` key of this anonymous hash. That's it!

---

Note that you can chain multiple calls of `map` together in a single statement, which is a powerful construct and often preferable to a regular  loop such as `foreach`. However, underneath it, a `map` is just another loop. :)

Comment: Technically, `map` does loop, much like `for`.

Comment: @TLP Thank you for the comment on the similarity between `map` and other loops. Added this to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should never run code without `use strict; use warnings;`. If you had, you would have gotten this fatal error:

```
Global symbol "%person_data" requires explicit package name at -e line 1.
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

In this code, you are missing the arrow operator which is used when the hash is inside a scalar value, like in your code. In other words this:

```
$person_data{'company'}
```

Should be this:

```
$person_data->{'company'}
```

The former refers to a hash which should have been declared like this:

```
my %person_data;
```

If you had used `strict` you would have avoided this problem.